# Impossible to graphically log in / Unable to create files

Tags: login, ecryptfs

I had a message preventing that my disk was almost full. I removed some files (several Gb's) and decided to restart my computer. Now I cannot log in with the graphical interface anymore, I get an error `Could not update .ICEauthority file`. I logged in in console mode (this works). The `.ICEauthority` file does not exist. I tried to create it, using `touch .ICEauthority` but that resulted in the following error (I get the same for any `touch file`):

```
ecryptfs_write_metadata_to_contents: Error attempting to write header information to lower file; rc = [-28]
ecryptfs_write_metadata: Error writing metadata out to lower file; rc = [-28]
Error writing headers: rc = [-28]
touch: impossible de faire un touch '.ICEauthority': Aucun espace disponible sur le périphérique
```

(I am in French locale: the last lines approx. reads "no available space on disk".)

Also, the output of `df` contains:

```
/dev/sda2            39110168    6104132    30989628  17% /
/dev/sda4           203160440  193966132    0        100% /home
/home/name/.Private 203160440  193966132    0        100% /home
```

So the system (?) considers that the partition of `/home` is full (`100%` used and `0` free) while there is a difference between the size of Used and Total Space.

Any clue how to fix my problem?

Comment: Your inodes may have run out. Please do `df -i`.

Comment: First I have set reserved block for the `/home` partition to 0 and I can now log in (I've recovered 8.8Gb free in the `/home` partition). But I still have a difference of ~40Gb between the announced Used space by `df` and by `du`. See **edit** for `df -i`.

Comment: It turns out it had nothing to do with inodes running out, as I've explained in the answer. Thanks anyway for suggesting this!

Answer (score 0):

**Problem solved (though some mistery remains):**

1. To be able to log in again, I set the number of reserved blocks of the `/home` partition (`/dev/sda4` in my case) to 0:

```
   sudo tune2fs -m 0 /dev/sda4
```

2. The huge discrepancy between the result of `df` and `du` I still had was due to something totally unrelated: I had installed and configured [`timeshift`](https://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/timeshift) and it used the ~40Gb of discrepancy I experienced.
3. The mistery: Before setting the number of reserved blocks to 0, the sizes that `df` printed were inconsistent: `free space + used space` was much smaller than `total space`. After using `tune2fs`, the equality came back...